# PyCharm - HTML file - Flask Inheritence using {% block content% } not working

Tags: python, pycharm, jinja2

I am trying to create template inheritance using Jinja2. I am using (basic.py) to define app and render "home.html". I created base.html as framework file that I want to inherit in home.html. Problem is that that the code

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

in my base1.html file is not getting recognized when I run base.py. These lines of code are greyed out in PyCharm pro editor Also, the following code in home.html that I am using to extend base.html is also not working (greyed out):

```
{% extends [enter image description here][1]base1.html %}
{% block content%}
<h1>Hello, How are you?</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I appreciate any help as there don't seem to be many direct answers available either on PyCharm site or anywhere else. Please see attached picture of code files. I do already have installed Flask package in my project.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution that worked. the solution is to select Jinja2 as the template language for for HTML template file type.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpELy.jpg)